# jQuery ajax call in IE - encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, internet-explorer-9, urlencode

I have an ajax POST request with some data being passed to the server side. 
This is all working nicely on all browsers, but in case I have some specific characters, it fails in IE9. For example, sending "John Smith" through POST works just fine, but if I try "Rafał Szukała" (please notice specific *l* letter) in IE9, the browser doesn't pass them properly so I end up with band server response. Mozilla's working fine with this string btw.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: Include the relevant parts of your code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using jquery by the tag on the question.  Therefore, if this is a [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call you're making, you can specify the content type of the data with `contentType` attribute.  You would need a unicode type like UTF-8.

This then needs decoded correctly on the server side.

At least that's my best guess. :P

Comment: Joseph, thanks for replying.
I've tried contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8" but no luck there :(

Comment: and are you sure it failed to post it in unicode, or was it that when you stored it in a database or whatever that it didn't retain the encoding?

Comment: I've just run into some new issues here, maybe your suggestion will work out after all, I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Some more feedback: this is how Mozilla sends post data:
type=wikiAPI&Entity=Rafa%25C5%2582_Szuka%25C5%2582a
Mozilla automatically sets this content type:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

IE9 posts it in the same way, and I manually added the same content type, but it fails again...

Comment: you could try parsing the string manually before sending it.  You would use the `escape()` function like so: `data: {name: escape(name)}`.  Unfortunately however, I need sleep.  post any other questions you have or whatever you find out and I'll take another look tomorrow. EDIT: never mind... you said it posts the same anyway... I must be the server settings then if that's the case, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The solution which worked for me is pretty close to what Joseph Marikle mentioned, with some more details:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
```